# how to understand this JavaScript code output?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
let { length } = "hello app"
console.log(length) //=> 9
```

why the output of console.log is 9(it seems like string's length)?  Actually, I can't understand the syntax of first line.

Comment: That is [destructuring syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: @PatrickEvans Yeah but destructuring works with objects isn't it so bit more explanation why it works also with primitive types which string literal is would be nicer I believe.

Comment: Strings are also objects, objects with a length property that you can destructure. So when you destructure a string this way, it's identical to `let length = "hello app".length;`